# Draggable and resizeable textarea inside of a div

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm Trying to create a div with a text area that is both draggable and resizable.  Sounds simple enough.   My problem however is that the text area and the div both are being made resizable independently of one another.  This causes the ui to be rather confusing.  I don't understand why the text area is resizable  as I'm not explicitly setting it as resizable.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working how I expected by making only the text area resizable and setting the "alsoResize" with the parent div and everything was made happy =)